# Microsoft UWP MediaPlayer Example throws Memory AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, xaml, video, uwp, media-player

The following [code sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/play-audio-and-video-with-mediaplayer#use-mediaplayer-in-frame-server-mode) from Microsoft is causing an external exception when used against UWP version 1903 Build 18362 and Nuget package Win2d 1.25.0

The memory access violation happens on mediaPlayer.CopyFrameToVideoSurface(inputBitmap);
And it happens no matter what video the MediaPlayer is trying to play.

The example_video.mkv file in the Assets folder is the file sample_640x360.mkv from [this video sample page](https://filesamples.com/formats/mkv). Ultimately I tried multiple file formats both local and streaming, and it didn't change the exception being thrown.

Also I tried locking the CanvasDevice as is seen by the CanvasLock which is commented out, but that also changed nothing.

**The Fatal Exception Thrown:**

```
System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs:**

```
using Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas;
using Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.Effects;
using Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.Xaml;
using System;
using Windows.Graphics.Display;
using Windows.Graphics.Imaging;
using Windows.Media.Core;
using Windows.Media.Playback;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace MediaPlayerTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
        SoftwareBitmap frameServerDest;
        CanvasImageSource canvasImageSource;

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mediaPlayer.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/example_video.mkv"));
            mediaPlayer.VideoFrameAvailable += mediaPlayer_VideoFrameAvailable;
            mediaPlayer.IsVideoFrameServerEnabled = true;
            mediaPlayer.Play();
        }

        // FROM: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/play-audio-and-video-with-mediaplayer#use-mediaplayer-in-frame-server-mode
        private async void mediaPlayer_VideoFrameAvailable(MediaPlayer sender, object args)
        {
            CanvasDevice canvasDevice = CanvasDevice.GetSharedDevice();

            await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                if (frameServerDest == null)
                {
                    // FrameServerImage in this example is a XAML image control
                    frameServerDest = new SoftwareBitmap(BitmapPixelFormat.Rgba8, (int)FrameServerImage.Width, (int)FrameServerImage.Height, BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore);
                }
                if (canvasImageSource == null)
                {
                    canvasImageSource = new CanvasImageSource(canvasDevice, (int)FrameServerImage.Width, (int)FrameServerImage.Height, DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().LogicalDpi);//96); 
                    FrameServerImage.Source = canvasImageSource;
                }

                using (CanvasBitmap inputBitmap = CanvasBitmap.CreateFromSoftwareBitmap(canvasDevice, frameServerDest))
                using (CanvasDrawingSession ds = canvasImageSource.CreateDrawingSession(Windows.UI.Colors.Black))
                {
                    // CanvasLock lk = canvasDevice.Lock();

                    mediaPlayer.CopyFrameToVideoSurface(inputBitmap);

                    // lk.Dispose();

                    var gaussianBlurEffect = new GaussianBlurEffect
                    {
                        Source = inputBitmap,
                        BlurAmount = 5f,
                        Optimization = EffectOptimization.Speed
                    };

                    ds.DrawImage(gaussianBlurEffect);

                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**MainPage.xaml:**

```
<Page
    x:Class="MediaPlayerTest.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MediaPlayerTest"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Play Video" FontSize="40" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="78" Margin="156,110,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="288" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <Image x:Name="FrameServerImage" Height="360" Width="640" Margin="156,246,704,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: When I downloaded the mkv file from your link and tested the code snippet, it can display frames in Image control and I didn't receive an exception when called CopyFrameToVideoSurface method. Can you provide a simple sample that can be reproduced for us to test?

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT I created this video in Zoom to show the error: https://app.box.com/s/xo69t3zsd71cp4kq9gq07wmc9nx66yzp It runs the exact sample above. I uninstalled all versions of Visual Studio first and all SDKs, then I re-installed Visual Studio 2019 and also ran a repair on it just to make sure

Comment: Could you please provide a simple sample that can be reproduced for us to test? It's helpful to find the issue.

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT I verified that the sample is valid as is. It only happens when the entirety of the Image control showing the video frame is on an extended screen as per the control panel display settings. Please see the sample video which clearly identifies and shows the bug in UWP: https://app.box.com/s/q97u1dnyk3tzh9lgyho9xue0ik91ddvk

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT The extended monitor shown in the last video is a 4K LG monitor in 3840x2160 resolution, as opposed to the primary laptop monitor that is not 4k in 1920x1080 resolution

Comment: If you test on another machine, will the same issue occur? In addition, can you tell us what your video driver you are using?

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT I am using the NVidia Quadro Desktop/Quadro Notebook Driver Release 418 Version 426.78 installed by the NVidia GeForce Experience display driver manager application. It is being run on a Dell Precision M4800 with freshly installed Windows 10 & Windows updates. Video card is the NVidia Quadro K1100M

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT I was able to reproduce the bug on 2 different laptops with the same exact specs using the same method.

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT If I am eligible for Microsoft Bug Bounty on this UWP bug, I would like to collect: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/msrc/bounty Please let me know.

Comment: I am not sure if it will help you but I found that  `canvasDevice.Dispose()` prevent of memory leaks. So try to add it as well.